# Grails throwing H2 WebServlet load error

Tags: grails, configuration, h2

I am trying to remove H2 from my Grails app. In my `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits("global") {
        excludes 'h2'
    }

    ...
}
```

And in my `Datasource.groovy` file:

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'
    singleSession = true
}
```

When I do a `run-app` my app runs fine in the browser, but in the console I see the following error output:

```
|Loading Grails 2.4.2
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
....................................
|Running Grails application
Error |
2014-12-06 06:13:58,476 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR [localhost].[/]  - Servlet  threw load() exception
Message: org.h2.server.web.WebServlet
    Line | Method
->>   59 | findClass in org.grails.plugins.tomcat.ParentDelegatingClassLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    358 | loadClass in     ''
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/
```

H2 comes with its own web servlet?!? **What is going on here, and what can I do to fix it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, H2 has a great web-based JDBC console that works with any JDBC driver, and it's configured by default in the development environment. It can be enabled or disabled for any environment though. It's described in the docs [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#databaseConsole). If you don't plan on using this and you're excluding the jar, you can disable it for all environments by adding

```
grails.dbconsole.enabled = false
```

to `Config.groovy` - just make sure it's a top-level property and not in an `environments` block.

It's a very convenient feature though, especially since it gives you access to the in-memory database that's used by default when you first create a project. But even when you move to a "real" database it's still a great utility for accessing your database. Unless the jar is causing a conflict, I'd remove the exclusion since the jar is only ~1.6MB.